# How to save many json objects in redis database using node.js

Tags: node.js, redis, couchdb

In my application im using node.js with redis database.How can i save many json objects in redis.

```
            db.save({
                description:'sdsd',userId:'324324',url:'http://www.abc.com/abc.html',appId:'123456'
          }, function (err, res) {
              if(err){
                  console.log(err);
                  return;
              }
              else{

                  console.log(res);
              }
          });
```

In couch db we can save the json objects again and again as document by using the above code.How to do this in redis.From their documentation i came to know below code save the json objects

```
               client.hmset("hosts", "mjr", "1", "another", "23", "home", "1234");
```

Again i want to save the other json object in same "hosts" like below

```
          client.hmset("hosts", "mjr", "2", "another", "33", "home", "1235");
```

How can i do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redis storage model is different from CouchDB.  In Redis, everything gets accessed by its key, so it all depends how you plan to retrieve your data.

So if you'd like to be able to retrieve data by `userId`, use this as the key.

```
redis.set('324324', {
  description:'sdsd',
  url:'http://www.abc.com/abc.html',
  appId:'123456'
  });
```

But if you need to retrieve a piece of data using more than one piece of the data, then redis may not be suitable.

In some cases, you may be able to use some tricks, so that to be able to query on both `userId` and `appId`, you could use `324324:123456` as the key, and query using

```
GET 324324:*
```

to get all apps for one user

or

```
GET *:123456
```

to get all users for a given app.

Comment: thanks for ur post.now i understood the structure of redis.i will try like this.

Comment: Can i query on both userId and appId like below

Comment: var query=userId+appId;   redis.get(query,function(err,res){ if(!err){  console.log(res)} });

Comment: if the key is `324324:123456`, you can use `GET 324324:123456`, but this will have to be an exact match (I'm using the redis-cli syntax, but that's easy to convert to the node equivalent.

Comment: i tried like this,is this correct..      var query="324324"+":"+"123456";
 console.log('query'+query);
 
 client.get(query,function(err,res){
  
  console.log(res);
  
 });

Comment: the above assumes you've done `redis.set('324324:123456', ...)`

Comment: sorry while saving i didn't include the appId.